# revisionId is omitted from Slides API response with new presentations

Tags: google-slides-api

Any newly created presentations no longer have a revisionId set. Previously a revisionId was set and updated whenever a presentation was modified. This ID was accessible when making requests with the Slides API.

The Slides API documentation still documents this ID:
https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations

The revisionId no longer appears in new presentations when accessing them with the Slides API. When making similar requests with older presentations they will still return and update the revisionId.

Example of how I am requesting the presentation data with a Node script:

```
const auth = await authorize();
const slides = google.slides({ version: 'v1', auth });
const response = await slides.presentations.get({ presentationId });
console.log(response.data)
```

Expected response:

```
{
  presentationId: '.....',
  pageSize: {
    .....
  },
  slides: [.....],
  title: 'new',
  masters: [.....],
  layouts: [],
  locale: 'en',
  **revisionId: 'REVISIONID',**
  notesMaster: {......}
}
```

Steps to replicate:

1. Create a new Slides presentation
2. Make a request via the Slides API to request the presentation
3. See output is missing the revisionId

Is anyone else experiencing this? Has this been permanently removed from the API? If so what alternatives can I use to check if the presentation data has changed.

Comment: When I tested your flow, I can confirm `revisionId` is included in the response from ["Method: presentations.get"](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/get). If I misunderstood your flow, please tell me.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for checking! I've actually just figured it out, the issue is that the presentation wasn't shared with edit permissions. If editing permissions are enabled the revisionId is provided again.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: The issue is that the presentation wasn't shared with editing permissions. If sharing permissions are set to "Editor" the revisionId is provided again.